# SQLite Database not getting updated

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

So Ive created an app where the user can input details about the movies he has watched such as name,cast,rating...ect and the details are stored in a database inside a table names which is initialized in the DataBaseHelper class as

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "table1";
```

in the below segment of code Ive created a list view and displayed the names of the movies with a checkbox in front of each name. where the check box if ticked mean that its a favorite else not a favorite...initially the column in the table which holds if the movie is a favorite is set to "no"
when ticked and button pressed  I want all the movie names with the tick on to update  to "yes" in the database.

DisplayActivity class with the list view

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DataBaseHelper myDb;
ListView movieNList;
Button addFavoritesB,button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    movieNList =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.moviesLV);
    myDb=new DataBaseHelper(this);
    addFavoritesB=(Button) findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    ArrayList<String> theList=new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data=myDb.getData();

    if (data.getCount()==0){
        Toast.makeText(DisplayActivity.this,"The Database is empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{

        //Adds data to the list view
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            theList.add(data.getString(1));
            Collections.sort(theList);
            ListAdapter listAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,theList);
            movieNList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        }
    }

    buttonAction();
}

public void buttonAction(){
    myDb.getWritableDatabase();
    addFavoritesB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String itemSelected="Selected items : \n";
            for (int i=0;i<movieNList.getCount();i++){
                if (movieNList.isItemChecked(i)){
                    itemSelected += movieNList.getItemAtPosition(i)+"\n";
                    System.out.println(itemSelected);
                    myDb.updateFavorites(itemSelected,"yes");
                    
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Method in DataBaseHelper class to update the favorites column

```
public boolean updateFavorites(String name,String favorites) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("FAVORITES", favorites);
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from table1 where name=? ", new String[]{name});
    if (res.getCount() > 0) {
        long result = db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "name=?", new String[]{name});
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

when I try it like this, the columns wont update....Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `itemSelected` is created correctly inside the `onClick()` listener, I suggest that you use a char like `"|"` as a delimiter instead of `"\n"` for the movie titles and remove `"Selected items : \n"` from the start of `itemSelected`.
Also move `myDb.updateFavorites(itemSelected,"yes");` out of the `for` loop, so that the `updateFavorites()` is called only once for all selected movies:

```
public void buttonAction(){
    myDb.getWritableDatabase();
    addFavoritesB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String itemSelected="|";
            for (int i=0;i<movieNList.getCount();i++){
                if (movieNList.isItemChecked(i)){
                    itemSelected += movieNList.getItemAtPosition(i)+"|";
                }
            }
            itemSelected += "|";
            myDb.updateFavorites(itemSelected,"yes");
        }
    });
}
```

Then use the `update()` method to update the table with the operator `LIKE` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
public int updateFavorites(String name, String favorites) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("FAVORITES", favorites);
    return db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "? LIKE '%|' || name || '|%'", new String[] {name});
}
```

Note that I changed the return type of `updateFavorites()` from `boolean` to `int()` because `db.update()` returns the number of updated rows.